# PHP call public variable in another class

Tags: php, function, class, variables

I am trying to call a public variable used in a class in another class. I am able to call the variable but it returns a blank array.

Code that I am working on,

**Class One:**

```
class fruits {
public $ID = array();

private function getFruitID() {
$fruitID = array('1' , '2', '3' , '4' , '5' );
return $fruitID;  
}

private function getFruitsName() {
$fruitName = array('apple' , 'orange' , 'kiwi' , 'grapes' , 'mango');
return $fruitName ;  
}

public function getstock() {    
$this->ID   = getFruitID();
/* Prints the ID list here */
$this->name = getFruitsName();
/* This function renders to the template */  

}

}
```

**Class Two:**

```
class TestPage{

public function displayFruits() {
require_once ('fruits.php');
$fruits = new fruits();
$data = $fruits->ID;
echo($data);
/* displays an empty array */
}     
}
```

When I echo $data inside displayFruits() on TestPage, it prints a blank array and not the actual ids. I am stuck with getting the ids on TestPage class. I could use a return, but that way I would end with just one variable, and I have multiple variables inside that function. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not contructing the array with anything ..

```
public $ID = array();
```

is blank... until you call `getFruitID`

you can add it into the constructor if you need.

[constructors PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

```
function __construct( ){
   $this->getstock();
}
```

This means when you create your object `new Fruit();`

It will assign the array in its creation.

Comment: Note that that should be `$this->getStock();`, since it's a method of the current class, not a global function (the mistake is in the question, but you've repeated it here).

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it is empty.

```
public $ID = array();
```

Add below to populate array

```
class TestPage{

    public function displayFruits() {
        require_once ('fruits.php');
        $fruits = new fruits();
        $fruits->getstock();
        $data = $fruits->ID;
        echo($data);

    }     
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but I can't really call getstock() as it gets values from various other private functions and returns the output to html template. Calling that function would print print other template-related details on displayFruits() function. Would it be possible to get the variable without calling getstock() ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @RachelJose The question you should ask yourself is, *why* does that function render to the template? It should be its purpose *either* to load data for later use, *or* to display data previously loaded, not both. The posh name for this is the Single Responsibility Principle, and it's considered a key part of designing good software.